# reading char by char from a stringbuilder

Tags: java

I'm writing a little application that receives instructions in a StringBuilder filled with "(" and ")", for every ( the application sums 1, for every ( it decreases 1. I know it's a bit weird but it's a puzzle and it had to be done like that.

I'm having problems reading the content from the stringbuilder, Eclipse is complaining that it cannot access the specified  index with charAt, what am I doing wrong?

I already checked and StringBuilder instructions is valid and properly filled with ( and ), no nulls or other symbols.

```
public void walker(StringBuilder instructions){
        for(int i=0; i<instructions.length();i++){
            if(instructions.charAt(0)==")"){
                //do something
            }
            else(){
                //do other thing
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Its `instructions.charAt(i)`

Comment: instructions.charAt(0)==')' find the difference...

Comment: "for every ( the application sums 1, for every ( it decreases 1" - so it does nothing?

Comment: Voting to close as Typo

Answer (score 1):

To use a `Char` in Java you use `'` not `"`

so it should be :

```
public void walker(StringBuilder instructions){
        for(int i=0; i<instructions.length();i++){
            if(instructions.charAt(0)==')'){   //<-- note the change of " to '
                //do something
            }
            else{
                //do other thing
            }
        }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

The above solves the complication problem however 
as @cricket noted, it should be `charAt(i)` for `correctness` of the code

Comment: I think should also be `charAt(i)`

Comment: It worked, thank you!!

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks, I've edited the answer

Comment: If you are editing for "`correctness`", also remove the `()` after `else`. I wouldn't add such things as "Edit" comments - just edit your answer. Also, it is `char`, not `Char`.

Comment: @AndyTurner lol, I didn't notice that at all , ty

Comment: @nafas I meant all of the edits, not just the `()`.